# android-sdks/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: installation, 32-bit, drivers

I just installed eclipse, the android sdk and jdk on a fresh installation for 64 bit fedora 14 , but by the time i create a new project i am getting the following error in the console:

> android-sdks/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

i am using a 64bit machine and i need to install some 32bit drivers,
so i am trying to install:

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs Reading Package Lists... Done Building
>   Dependency Tree... Done E: Couldn't find package ia32-libs

Anyone help me how to resolve 64bit fedora 14 machine libz.so.1 problems

Answer (score 113):

Running Kubuntu 13.10 (x64) and I used lib32z1, which fixed it for me.

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

Comment: It worked for me too. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 (x64). Thanks.

Comment: Rock on. You are a hero and a scholar of the 32-bit arts.

Comment: Works for XUbuntu 14.10 as well!!

Comment: Works for Xubuntu 12.04 (x64).

Comment: It didn't worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 (x64). I managed to fix it installing another package: 

`sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386`

Comment: @rchavarria I needed both! i think if you would have installed the `libstdc++6:i386` before `lib32z1` as i did, then it would have worked for you! Cheers

Comment: I'm considering to switch to 32 bit environment due to these errors. This one was solved on Ubuntu 14.04(x64) this way but it's frustrating

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked well.. I was facing the same issues in Ubuntu 15 64 bit version.

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04 here, had to install both as well: ```sudo apt-get instal lib32z1 libstdc++6:i386```

Answer (score 27):

Lukacsa, it works! simple and great suggestion

Try this:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

This will resolve 64 bit machine's 32 bit compatibility issue~!

(Tested with: CentOS 6.2 64-bit and Fedora 22 64-bit)

Comment: I've also need to do this: yum install libstdc++.i686

Comment: Works for Fedora 24 with `dnf`.

Answer (score 13):

**try this this solved problem for me, had 64 bit ubuntu 14.05**

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue using the solution shared in this blog post:

http://ideid.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/resolve-shared-library-problem-with.html

Here is the solution for convenience:

"Android SDK is compiled for a 32-bit GNU/Linux system, and your  system is a 64-bit system. To solve this error, install the 32-bit versions of all the most commonly used libraries, by installing the ia32-libs package

Go to the terminal and type the following command.

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

This will solve the issue."

Hope this helps

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` does not work anymore. Any new fix?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue on my centos machine.

check out this:
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9556/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-fedora/

For me it worked by:
yum install libstdc++.i386 zlib.i386

Answer (score 1):

yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686

for RHEL this worked . My machine was 64bit machine,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Archlinux.

You need to enable the multilib repository in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Update pacman and install the 32 bit version of zlib:

```
pacman -Suy
pacman -S lib32-zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

for OpenSuse you simply have to install libz1-32bit

```
zypper install libz1-32bit
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a :i386 suffix to the package name for the package manager correctly identify it:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

aapt is a 32 bit app so your 64 bit machine needs these libraries loaded

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a six year old question with eleven other answers it is important to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, and how it is different from the existing answers, and why you've included each part of the apt-get command.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: sudo yum install zlib.i686