# Android Studio mergeDebugResources issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I seem to be having difficulties switching to Android Studio. I created a new Project in Android Studio 0.4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10. but I have been plagued with issues. I originally had issues on a windows box when it was first distributed which is why i ignored it until recently. I fixed a few things with gradle but seem to still be having other issues and I ended up following a few suggestions from the links bellow though nothing helped. Does anyone have any suggestions.

[mergedebugresources-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception)

[installing android studio in ubuntu](http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/05/16/installing-android-studio-ide-in-ubuntu-hello-world-application/)

[How to Install Android studio in ubuntu 13.10](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2013/10/23/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-linux-13-10/)

I've also installed fastboot and adb in terminal and I have also arbitrarily uninstalled whatever jdk I was using prior had and re-installed java 7 instead of 8 (since it would not install for some reason) via

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer* 
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

bellow is the error message i am currently receiving

```
Execution failed for task ':helloandroid:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> Error: Failed to run command:
>       /home/kyle/Development/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt s -i /home/kyle/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloAndroid/helloandroid/build/exploded-bundles/ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901.aar/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_textfield_search_right_default_holo_light.9.png -o /home/kyle/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloAndroid/helloandroid/build/res/all/debug/drawable-hdpi/abc_textfield_search_right_default_holo_light.9.png
>     Error Code:
>       127
>     Output:
>       /home/kyle/Development/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [android-sdks/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020298/android-sdks-build-tools-17-0-0-aapt-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz)

Comment: I have tried sudo apt-get install ia32-libs which wasn't found and resulted in me reinstalling libc6-i386 and installing libncurses5:i386 and libstdc++6:i386 as well as 3 other libraries whose name i cannot remember

Comment: I have also installed lib32stdc++6 & lib32z1 and rebuilt the project then created a new one to see if i get the same issues and the problem persists with a blank project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lib32z1 - worked for me.

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`