# Cannot build release Android in visual studio

Tags: android, json, cordova, apk, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to get the apk for android to release to the mobile store, but every time I try to build in release I get this error.

```
Reading build config file: C:\ProjectName\build.json
    1>  ERROR building one of the platforms: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿
    1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
    1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿
```

Now I've been following these instructions [Package your Cordova App](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/) and it says to put all my keystore stuff into the build.json, but I didn't have one of those. I couldn't find a .json extension to add it, so I just used the .resjson but renamed it build.json. Then I added all my keystore stuff into that.

Anyone have any idea what i've done wrong? :(

Comment: You are doing it correctly. The `build.json` file can be made through rename from any empty file. Please make sure the keystore is created correctly and the information that describes your key in `build.json` is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the correct line endings in your build.json file.

On the File menu, choose Advanced Save Options, you can control it there.

[image]

Comment: the recommended encoding for json is utf-8, and in any case, it should be a unicode compatible encoding, not cp1252 (ever).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this answer, it may be the same issue you're facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512740/2344390)