# Android gradle processReleaseResources failed android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt java.io.IOException

Tags: java, android, linux, gradle, centos

When I was trying to build an android project on `Centos 6.6 64bit`, it failed with unclear message. I want to share my solution that worked so far. The error message doesn't quite clearly inform the culprit. It turn out that `appt` tool uses native libraries from the OS. After tracking down the dependencies, I ran this to install them:

`sudo yum install -y glibc.i686 zlib.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++.i686`

I got these messages at first attempt:

```
08:54:09.909 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.629 secs, idle: 0.026 secs
08:54:09.911 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
08:54:09.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:54:09.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:54:09.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:54:09.920 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:54:09.920 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':color-picker-view:processReleaseResources'.
08:54:09.920 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt''
08:54:09.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:54:09.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
08:54:09.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

And then I tried with `gradle clean build --stacktrace --info` to get this:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':color-picker-view:processReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:196)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:325)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:65)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt" (in directory "/tmp/color-picker-view"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        ... 4 more
```

To check the existence and tracked them down, I called:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt
bash: /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
$ ll /lib/ld-linux.so.2
ls: cannot access /lib/ld-linux.so.2: No such file or directory
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt
bash: /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt
/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0_rc3/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8):

Check this answer to a previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505268 
It says you need to install lib32z1.
    sudo apt-get install lib32z1
Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I couldn't find it that time.

Comment: Glad to hear that.