# "ionic build android" build failed

Tags: ionic-framework

i am getting following error while run "ionic build android"

can help me out of this

```
Running command: /Users/tapan/Desktop/Today/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/tapan/Desktop/Today
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/tapan/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/tapan/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.926 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /Users/tapan/Desktop/Today/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/tapan/Desktop/Today/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/tapan/Desktop/Today/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/tapan/Desktop/Today/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

also see snapshot

[image]

i have tried almost everything thing but not find how to build this android app,i also have removed android project and again create new android project, but still same error

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
```

please help me

Comment: I have the same problem. Yesterday everything was good

Comment: Same problem for me. Since this is a recent problem, I assume it's based on a package update, but unfortunately today is the first day I've tried to an android build. Do you have any idea what packages you updated since yesterday @BillyLogan?

Comment: same problem with me. i am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS , have you found any solution. my project was working perfect, but for some HW issue i have to format my pc. and after that BOOM. . i can run **ionic serve** but can't run ionic build android or ionic run android

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Fedora 23 x64) I had to install the following packages:

```
dnf install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

Found that out because the execution of android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt gave me some errors.

Sources:

http://www.howtodoityourself.org/how-to-fix-libld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory.html

[android-sdks/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020298/android-sdks-build-tools-17-0-0-aapt-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the packages may not be installed in SDK manager. Check the below link for more details:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html