# Tensorflow Inception Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow

I am trying to build the [TensorFlow Android Camera Demo][1].
As i understand the error something is wrong with build-tools/23.0.1 removed it and reinstalled it but to no effect. what is wrong or any thoughts on how to find out what the problem is?

used:
ndk: android-ndk-r12b
tensorflow: master branch  ( tried 0.8 and 0.9 as well )

i tried to use buildtoolversion 24.0.0 and got a different error (included below)

WORKSPACE file:

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    build_tools_version = "23.0.1",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/home/boss/Android/Sdk",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/home/boss/Downloads/android-ndk-r12b",
    api_level=21)
```

Error: buildtool 23.0.1

```
ERROR: /home/boss/Downloads/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD:47:1: Processing Android resources for //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed: namespace-sandbox failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master && \
  exec env - \
  /home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master/_bin/namespace-sandbox @/home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master/bazel-sandbox/565ee075-9d3c-4af1-adce-59fc5a2f3c06-0.params -- bazel-out/host/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/resources_processor --buildToolsVersion 23.0.1 --aapt bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary --annotationJar external/androidsdk/tools/support/annotations.jar --androidJar external/androidsdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar --primaryData tensorflow/examples/android/res:tensorflow/examples/android/assets:tensorflow/examples/android/AndroidManifest.xml --rOutput bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo_symbols/R.txt --srcJarOutput bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo.srcjar --proguardOutput bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/proguard/tensorflow_demo/_tensorflow_demo_proguard.cfg --manifestOutput bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo_processed_manifest/AndroidManifest.xml --resourcesOutput bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo_files/resource_files.zip --packagePath bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo.ap_ --debug --packageForR org.tensorflow.demo).
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 17, 2016 11:51:48 PM com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceProcessingAction main
SEVERE: Error during merging resources
Error: Failed to run command:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary s -i /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/tmp-deduplicated/tensorflow/examples/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png -o /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/merged_resources/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
Error Code:
        127
Output:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:54)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:113)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceProcessor.mergeData(AndroidResourceProcessor.java:724)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceProcessingAction.main(AndroidResourceProcessingAction.java:254)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary s -i /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/tmp-deduplicated/tensorflow/examples/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png -o /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/merged_resources/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
Error Code:
        127
Output:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:123)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:96)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.AaptCruncher.crunchPng(AaptCruncher.java:58)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:188)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "main" Error: Failed to run command:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary s -i /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/tmp-deduplicated/tensorflow/examples/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png -o /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/merged_resources/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
Error Code:
        127
Output:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:54)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:113)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceProcessor.mergeData(AndroidResourceProcessor.java:724)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceProcessingAction.main(AndroidResourceProcessingAction.java:254)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary s -i /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/tmp-deduplicated/tensorflow/examples/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png -o /tmp/android_resources_tmp1770729823994372609/merged_resources/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
Error Code:
        127
Output:
        bazel-out/host/bin/external/androidsdk/aapt_binary.runfiles/androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:123)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:96)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.AaptCruncher.crunchPng(AaptCruncher.java:58)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:188)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build
```

error: buildtool 24.0.0

```
ERROR: /home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/external/gif_archive/BUILD:14:1: C++ compilation of rule '@gif_archive//:gif' failed: namespace-sandbox failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/boss/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin \
  /home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master/_bin/namespace-sandbox @/home/boss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_boss/f65f721012b7fd201233c0708275aaf3/execroot/tensorflow-master/bazel-sandbox/937cd00e-9340-4e7e-b3fe-a3006d83a7e6-2.params -- /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wl,-z,-relro,-z,now -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -iquote external/gif_archive -iquote bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/gif_archive -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib -isystem bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -MD -MF bazel-out/host/bin/external/gif_archive/_objs/gif/external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib/quantize.d -c external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib/quantize.c -o bazel-out/host/bin/external/gif_archive/_objs/gif/external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib/quantize.o).
external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib/quantize.c:17:29: fatal error: gif_lib_private.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem: 64 bit machine's 32 bit compatibility
Solution found: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020298/android-sdks-build-tools-17-0-0-aapt-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz)